# Getting an exponential trend without the first data points

Tags: time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, trend

So I'm trying to extract an exponential trend.

I have a series with x values 0, 1, 2, 3....

My problem is that my first point isn't (0, 1), I.e. the intercept of an exponential trend line

My data might be (0,400), (1,410), (2,425).....

So this means that my x values aren't correct (they have been shifted and we don't have the values before that). My first x value might be 1000 for example.

Is my only option to subtract 400 from all my y values, extract the trend and add a constant of 400?
I think that would be a bad idea, especially if my first point was an outlier.

My fit improves if I shift the x values, should I just shift back really far?

Basically I want to get an exponential trend without knowing this shift in x values
Is this possible?

I'm using Python, so no excel please ;)

Comment: 1. What makes you say that an "exponential trend line" would pass through (0,1)? What definition of "exponential trend" do you have? 2. I seen your y-values are integers. Are they counts?

Answer (score 0):

An exponential trend would be generally regarded as having a form like $\mu_{Y|X} = A\cdot B^x$ (or $A\cdot B^t$ on a trend against time),  whence $\log(\mu_{Y|X}) = a + b x$ where $a=\log A$ and $b = \log B$ (where the $\log$ is to any consistent base).

This means it is perfectly possible for it to pass through (0,400) because of the scaling factor $A$.

The question then comes how to fit such a trend and that depends on how you conceive of the noise (/randomness) entering the relationship.

If you can reasonably condition on $x$ (/are without danger of substantial observational error in it) then there are many possibilities, but three common ones:

1. spread of noise is constant as $x$ changes. In this case you could use nonlinear least squares on the original data (or possibly a form of weighted regression with the approach in 2.)
2. spread of noise increases as $x$ increases. In this case you could take logs as indicated above and perform ordinary linear regression
3. spread of noise proportional to $\sqrt{x}$. This would often be seen as a reasonable approximation in the case of count data (and, sometimes, in other cases). In this situation a common choice would be to fit a (perhaps quasi-)Poisson GLM.